# SVN merge reintegrate fails with error: (retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported)

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 and SVN server (svnserve) 1.6.11, when I try to 'Merge - Reintegrate a branch' I get this error:

```
SVN merge reintegrate fails with error: (retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported)
```

Recommendations elsewhere tell me that this message occurs when either the client or server is older than 1.5, but this does not help me.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the repository format version, which is not automatically updated when the server is.

I have admin access to the repository, so checking `<path_to_repo>/db/format` showed `2` which corresponds to server version 1.4. I backed up the repository:

```
svnadmin dump <path_to_repo> | gzip > afullrepobackupname.svn.gz
```

and upgraded it:

```
svnadmin upgrade <path_to_repo>
```

Now `<path_to_repo>/db/format` contains:

```
4
layout linear
```

which corresponds to server version 1.6 (3 would be 1.5).

Now my TortoiseSVN can 'Merge - Reintegrate a branch' successfully.